# Is it possible to have a canvas next to another canvas without space on the bottom?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I hope to have two canvas for two plots left to right. It seems that the second canvas will be created below the first canvas automatically, and with position specified, their will be a large space below the canvas.

As canvases are created within a loop in my project, there are too many white spaces on the web, which I wish to have them gone with javascript.

Below is what I have.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">             
            var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
            canv.setAttribute('width', 200);
            canv.setAttribute('height', 200);
            canv.setAttribute('id', 'canv'+{{res.2}});
            document.body.appendChild(canv);
            var C = document.getElementById(canv.getAttribute('id'));
             if (C.getContext) {              
                if (C.getContext) {
                        new Chart(document.getElementById(canv.getAttribute('id')), {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: ["a1","a2","a3"],
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: ["AAA"],
                                    backgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 0.5)",
                                    borderColor : "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                                    data: [{{res.3}},{{res.4}},{{res.5}}] //numeric value
                                },
                            ]
                        },

        options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
                    });
                }
             }

             var canv2 = document.createElement("canvas");
            canv2.setAttribute('width', 200);
            canv2.setAttribute('height', 200);
            canv2.setAttribute('id', 'canv2_'+{{res.2}});
            document.body.appendChild(canv2);
            var C2 = document.getElementById(canv2.getAttribute('id'));
            C2.style.left='200px';
            C2.style.top='-200px';
            C2.style.position="relative";
             if (C2.getContext) {              
                if (C2.getContext) {
                        new Chart(document.getElementById(canv2.getAttribute('id')), {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: ["b1","b2","b3"],
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: ["BBB"],
                                    backgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 0.5)",
                                    borderColor : "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                                    data: [{{res.12}},{{res.13}},{{res.14}}] //numeric value
                                },
                            ]
                        },

        options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
                    });
                }
             }

                                </script>
```

Above leaves spaces of height 200 below every `canv` and `canv2` created.

How can I have them disappear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: set width and height directly with `canv.width = 200` then try using position absoulute and float to get them to stack side-by-side with no whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below? If you need more specific placement on page perhaps wrap them in a container that can be more easily moved around.

Edit: Updated to include centering CSS. Might be a bit tight on the snippet preview mind.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    html, body{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
        padding:0px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #canvas_container{
        position: absolute;
        left:50%; /* put 50% of containing div's width to my left */
        transform: translate(-50%); /* now move me back half of my own width */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas_container">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createCanvas() {
            let canv = document.createElement('canvas')
            canv.height = 150;
            canv.width = 150;
            canv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            canv.style.border = '1px solid black'
            canv.style.position = 'relative';
            canv.style.float = 'left';
            document.getElementById('canvas_container').appendChild(canv);
        }
        createCanvas();
        createCanvas();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried adding `C2.style.float = 'left';`  but from the second record,  texts and canvas 1  moved to right by 200px, causing overlap with canvas 2 which is still on the 200-400 pixels left to right.

Comment: Do you mind sharing more on the container? I used <div class="container"> </div> outside the javascript and did some css. The .css file successfully loaded but does not affect the page at all. Am I using the container the correct way?

Comment: This is the .css I tried  .container {
margin-left: 15%;
display: inline-block;
style.position: relative;
style.float: left;
display: flex;
}  Nothing changes with its presence

Comment: It's not super clear what you're trying to do. Do you need two canvases flush side-by-side to eachother, but centered on page together?

Comment: I am trying to build a web app that will return a list of tuples. For every tuple, text values will be displayed on the page, followed by graphs made by numeric values in the tuple. I hope to have multiple canvas side by side, under displayed texts, for each tuple turned.

Comment: Updated answer with some CSS changes for centering. Multiple containers like that can center your canvas pairs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your method and have a problem. Say my text values in the tuples are in ID "text_container". The two containers seem to work independently. Graphs overlap with the Text. I tried with  `document.body.appendChild(canv)` instead of `document.getElementById('canvas_container').appendChild(canv)`, the second tuple will start beside the first pair of canvases on the right, and so on,  even though I do not specify any style for “text_container". This is too confusing. What do I need to specify for text_container  for the second tuple under the canvases before ?

Comment: I found the solution with the right search word. Just add `style="clear:both;"` in the text_container. Thank you.